# How to compile a java application which uses Google webdriver from comand line without ant

Tags: java, ant, compiler-construction, webdriver

I want to compile an example code which using google`s webdriver.

I saved webdriver into /home/iyo/webdriver. My code is:

```
package com.googlecode.webdriver.example;



import com.googlecode.webdriver.By;

import com.googlecode.webdriver.WebDriver;

import com.googlecode.webdriver.WebElement;

import com.googlecode.webdriver.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class FirstTest  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();        

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement element =
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'q']"));
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
        element.submit();
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

    }

}
```

But I with

```
javac -cp /home/iyo/webdriver FirstTest.java
```

I got errors like this:

```
FirstTest.java:5: cannot find symbol
```

symbol  : class By

location: package com.googlecode.webdriver

import com.googlecode.webdriver.By;

```
                           ^
```

FirstTest.java:7: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class WebDriver

location: package com.googlecode.webdriver

import com.googlecode.webdriver.WebDriver;

```
                           ^
```

FirstTest.java:9: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class WebElement

location: package com.googlecode.webdriver

import com.googlecode.webdriver.WebElement;

```
                           ^
```

FirstTest.java:11: package com.googlecode.webdriver.htmlunit does not exist

import com.googlecode.webdriver.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

```
                                    ^
```

FirstTest.java:19: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class WebDriver

location: class com.googlecode.webdriver.example.FirstTest

```
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();        

    ^
```

FirstTest.java:19: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class HtmlUnitDriver

location: class com.googlecode.webdriver.example.FirstTest

```
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();        

                           ^
```

FirstTest.java:27: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class WebElement

location: class com.googlecode.webdriver.example.FirstTest

```
    WebElement element =

    ^
```

FirstTest.java:29: cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable By

location: class com.googlecode.webdriver.example.FirstTest

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'q']"));

                       ^
```

8 errors

It`s possible to use it whitouht Ant?(The code in NetBeans or Eclipse work well, but I don`t want to use them.) Only with javac?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the [webdriver homepage](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/wiki/GettingStarted) one can read

- Add $WEBDRIVER_HOME/common/build/webdriver-common.jar to the CLASSPATH
- Add $WEBDRIVER_HOME/htmlunit/build/webdriver-htmlunit.jar to the CLASSPATH
- Add all the Jar files under $WEBDRIVER_HOME/htmlunit/lib/runtime to the CLASSPATH

So you have to put all the jar files behind `-cp` like that

```
javac -cp /home/iyo/webdriver/common/build/webdriver-common.jar:/home/iyo/webdriver/common/build/webdriver-htmlunit.jar FirstTest.java
```

You probably have to add all the jar files from htmlunit/lib/runtime to the classpath as well.

Comment: I run it exactly with your parameters (+I add JAR from $WEBDRIVER_HOME/htmlunit/lib/runtime) but it has got still same problems.

Comment: Perhaps you post the complete line you finally executed then we can see what the problem is.